# Dojo Calendar is only showing numbers instead of month names

Tags: calendar, dojo

I currently have a problem with Dojo's calendar. It doesn't seem to be showing the name of the month when the locale is switched to zh-tw.

Instead of getting:

一月
二月
三月
。。。

we get

1
2
3
...

We don't have this problem when Dojo the locale is set to en. This is somewhat related to https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10490.

Anyone have a clue as to how to fix this? :)

Thanks!

Comment: You can modify the file http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/dojo/trunk/cldr/nls/zh-tw/gregorian.js and issue bug fix to Dojo. Since you're native Chinese speaker, I think it should be welcomed.

Comment: @ŁukaszLech It's not really a 'bug' in their gregorian.js file I think. It seems that there's something wrong with how the NLS file is being loaded. There could be some delay in loading the zh-tw file and loads a default JS file instead.

Answer (score 1):

That's because they implemented it that way. You can look at the [source code](http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/dojo/trunk/cldr/nls/zh-tw/gregorian.js) and see that the months are numbered. You can even compare it to the [English](http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/dojo/trunk/cldr/nls/en/gregorian.js) version.

As far as I know there is no way to extend or override this, so you will have to extend the `dijit.Calendar._MonthDropDown` yourself and hardcode it (not that this is a best practice).

Comment: Why not simply **change** that file?

Comment: I have already tried to edit the gregorian.js file before for both zh and zh-tw, still no luck. I encounter this by the way in WebSphere Portal developed using Web Experience Factory.

Comment: @Lukasz Lech if you update Dojo you have to maintain these changes. And it seems he is using WebSphere Portal, if he installes a fixpack, then he will probably have to update it too.

Comment: So it's probably best to fix it locally and issue the patch to Dojo.